# Shell sort complexity for other variations

Tags: c++, sorting, complexity-theory

So the code below has complexity of O(N^2), is there an easy way to edit this code to give complexity of O(n^(3/2)) and another of O(n^(4/3)). Theres some hints there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Gap_sequences but I am having issues implementing it.
(My task it to compare algorithm speed of those three in graph)

```
#include  <iostream>

using namespace std;

int shellSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2)
    {
        for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1)
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            int j;

            for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap)
                arr[j] = arr[j - gap];

            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {12, 34, 54, 2, 3}, i;
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    cout << "Array before sorting: \n";
    printArray(arr, n);

    shellSort(arr, n);

    cout << "\nArray after sorting: \n";
    printArray(arr, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"I am having issues implementing it" - you forgot to mention what those issues are.

Comment: Do you really want to slow down the sort ? You can sort your int[] with the complexity O(n*log(n))

Comment: I need to slow down the sort because my task is to compare them and make graphs. So I need seperate versions for n^(3/2) and n^(4/3) based on this code.

Comment: @ArnoltInfernKitler The edit you made together with the comment confuses me. _I need to slow down the sort_ but the requirements are changed to speed it up?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just tried to clarify becasue bruno asked if I really want to slow down the sort and proposed O(n*log(n)) which I don't want becasue my task is to compare  O(N^2), O^(3/2) and O^(4/3)

Comment: @ArnoltInfernKitler It's the _I need to slow down the sort_ comment I find confusing since both O(n^(3/2)) and O(n^(4/3)) are faster than O(n^2) but perhaps I just misunderstood it.

Comment: So this part " for (int gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2)" is used by term (N/2^k). Any idea how to do it for (2^k)-1 ??

Comment: Tried something like this https://imgur.com/6GJREIh

Comment: @ArnoltInfernKitler No, not without reading up on the algorithm. I did however make a small edit suggestion to clean up the code at [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-program-for-shellsort/) where you got it from.